# Android Fragment Unexpected Error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working on Android Project where I need to give a tabs in a page, So I am using Fragments for the same,
I have successfully created fragments, But in the main page where I've code to join all fragment, its giving error that

'Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'com.android.mads.madses.LoginInfoFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' less... 
addFrag
(android.support.v4.app.Fragment,
String)
in ViewPagerAdapter cannot be applied
to
(com.android.mads.madses.LoginInfoFragment,
String)'

I am not getting what exactly the error it.
Can anyone help me out with this please?

Here is the complete java code

```
  package com.android.mads.madses;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.android.mads.madses.LoginInfoFragment;
import com.android.mads.madses.VechicleInfoFragment;
import com.android.mads.madses.PersonalInfoFragment;
import com.android.mads.madses.ContactInfoFragment;


public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFrag(new LoginInfoFragment(), "LoginInfo");
        adapter.addFrag(new PersonalInfoFragment(), "PersonalInfo");
        adapter.addFrag(new ContactInfoFragment(), "ContactInfo");
        adapter.addFrag(new VechicleInfoFragment(), "VechicleInfo");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the import statements for LoginInfoFragment, ensure it is using 'import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;'

Explanation:

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

This is from android support library which allows older versions of android to use newer features of Android. This allows backwards compatibility.

```
android.app.Fragment
```

This is the real implementation of Fragment and only supports Android (3.0+) I believe.

Use support.v4 if you want your app to support older versions.

Comment: Can You please explain the difference between two?